# WordPress site goes blank frequently?

Tags: php, wordpress

My WordPress site goes blank frequently. It goes blank then and there. I don't see it go blank only after doing a particular action.
My guess is that it may due to some memory issues. Kindly help me out to resolve this error.

Comment: You have to replace `define( 'WP_DEBUG', false);` with `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);` in your wp-config.php. So error and notice will be displayed. And from that you recognize that why the site goes blank.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

enable debug mode in wp-config.php file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); // define in config file 

define( 'WP_DEBUG', false);
```

to

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

If there is any error it will display and then try to fix errors

Answer (score 0):

***define('WP_DEBUG', true);***

this only hide the error not resolving it.At development stage of any project it should be place true to find out the error in the code